# Gensim built-in model.load function and Python Pickle.load file

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I was trying to use Gensim to import GoogelNews-pretrained model on some English words (sampled 15 ones here only stored in a txt file with each per line, and there are no more context as corpus). Then I could use "model.most_similar()" to get their similar words/phrases for them. But actually the file loaded from Python-Pickle method couldn't be used for gensim-built-in `model.load()` and `model.most_similar()` function directly.

how should I do to cluster the 15 English words (and more in the future), since I couldn't train and save and load a model  from the beginning?

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

GOOGLE_WORD2VEC_MODEL = '../GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'

GOOGLE_ENGLISH_WORD_PATH = '../testwords.txt'

GOOGLE_WORD_FEATURE = '../word.google.vector'

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(GOOGLE_WORD2VEC_MODEL, binary=True) 

word_vectors = {}

#load 15 words as a test to word_vectors

with open(GOOGLE_ENGLISH_WORD_PATH) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if line:                
            word = line
            print(line)
            word_vectors[word]=None
try:
    import cPickle
except :
    import _pickle as cPickle

def save_model(clf,modelpath): 
    with open(modelpath, 'wb') as f: 
        cPickle.dump(clf, f) 

def load_model(modelpath): 
    try: 
        with open(modelpath, 'rb') as f: 
            rf = cPickle.load(f) 
            return rf 
    except Exception as e:        
        return None 

for word in word_vectors:
    try:
        v= model[word]
        word_vectors[word] = v
    except:
        pass

save_model(word_vectors,GOOGLE_WORD_FEATURE)

words_set = load_model(GOOGLE_WORD_FEATURE)

words_set.most_similar("knit", topn=3)
```

> ```
> ---------------error message--------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-8-86c15e366696> in <module>
> ----> 1 words_set.most_similar("knit", topn=3)
>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
> ---------------error message--------
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `word_vectors` as a Python `dict`:

```
word_vectors = {}
```

Then your `save_model()` function just saves that raw `dict`, and your `load_model()` loads that same raw `dict`.

Such dictionary objects **don't** implement the `most_similar()` method, which is specific to the `KeyedVectors` interface (& related classes) of `gensim`.

So, you'll have to leave the data inside a `KeyedVectors`-like object to be able to use `most_similar()`.

Fortunately, you have a few options.

If you happened to need the just the **first** 15 words from inside the `GoogleNews` file (or first 15,000, etc), you could use the optional `limit` parameter to only read that many vectors:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(GOOGLE_WORD2VEC_MODEL, limit=15, binary=True)
```

Alternatively, if you really need to select an arbitrary subset of the words, and assemble them into a new `KeyedVectors` instance, you could re-use one of the classes inside `gensim` instead of a plain `dict`, then add your vectors in a slightly different way:

```
# instead of a {} dict
word_vectors = KeyedVectors(model.vector_size)  # re-use size from loaded model
```

...then later inside your loop of each `word` you want to add...

```
# instead of `word_vectors[word] = _SOMETHING_`
word_vectors.add(word, model[word])
```

Then you'll have a `word_vectors` that is an actual `KeyedVectors` object. While you *could* save that via plain Python-pickle, at that point you might as well use the `KeyedVectors` built-in `save()` and `load()` - they may be more efficient on large vector sets (by saving large sets of raw vectors as a separate file which should be kept alongside the main file). For example:

```
word_vectors.save(GOOGLE_WORD_FEATURE)
```

...

```
words_set = KeyedVectors.load(GOOGLE_WORD_FEATURE)

words_set.most_similar("knit", topn=3)  # should work
```

Comment: Thank you so much, gojomo! It's done with your advice.

Comment: One other note: the `.add()` operation essentially re-creates a big backing numpy array each call, copying all existing vectors with what's being added. Starting small and staying small, that's no big deal. But if you were working with a large number of word-vectors, it could become slow/inefficient. (Adding 1 vector to a set of 1 million would allocate a new 1,000,001 array, copy over all 1 million old, add the 1 new. Adding 1 more, allocate a 1,000,002 array, copy over 1,000,001 vectors, add the 1 new. Etc.) So if using this for bigger sets, `.add()` in fewer batches or a single batch.